# Unable to run flask app with apache and mod-wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

Here is the structure :

```
app :
  -- app.py
  -- main.py
  -- manage.py
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_script import Manager
from config import Configuration

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Configuration)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
manager = Manager(app)
```

manage.py

```
from app import manager
from main import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

main.py

```
from app import app  # import our Flask app
from app import manager

import models
import views

from series.blueprint import series
app.register_blueprint(series, url_prefix='/series')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I am able to run my app as `python main.py` but when I hook it up with apache and wsgi, it doesn't work :

I get "Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

/etc/httpd/conf.d/blog.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/newblog/app/wsgi.py
    <Directory /var/www/newblog/app>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/newblog/app")
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages")
from app import app as application
```

Please help!

Comment: Why are you not posting that stuff if it's the part that doesn't work?

Comment: What means `doesn't work` ? Do you get error message in browser or in apache logs ? Add this in question.

Comment: Nothing in the apache logs. I get 'The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.'

Comment: You are importing `views` and `models` but I don't see them in your structure or your code.

Comment: The ``VirtualHost`` doesn't have ``ServerName`` in it. Is that all of what you have in the ``VirtualHost``? If you have other ``VirtualHost`` definitions, including a default one as Apache would normally have on a Linux system, your ``VirtualHost`` would be ignored as Apache would have no way to match it based on name based virtual host matching. Instead request would be handled by first ``VirtualHost`` Apache finds, which is usually the default one. What is the URL you are using to access your web application?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it didn't work that way. I got rid of main.py and manage.py and put everything in app.py then it started working. I would still wait for the right answer if anyone can help fix whats wrong with above modular situation